# Produce single page of HTML?

Tags: gitbook

Is there a way to have `gitbook` produce a single page of HTML from a document?  I've seen smatterings of conversations about an [older option](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook/issues/54) in the Issues, but don't see any documentation about it with the current version.

Was this option removed?  Any way to get it back?

Comment: I would like to see this, too. The generated PDFs have a page break between major headings, which can create an enormous amount of blank space in a paged document.